# React-Bootstrap-Typeahead: Capture moment before setting selection into box (to allow conditional rejection)

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

In React-Boostrap-Typeahead, I need to capture the moment after the mouse has been clicked, but **before** the menu selection gets loaded into the Typeahead's box.

This is because I need to check items being selected, and for some of them, I need to display an alert with a Yes/No warning. Only if Yes is clicked can I proceed with setting that value into the box. Otherwise I need to reject the selection and keep it whatever it was prior to the mouse click.

- I can't use `onChange` because by that point the selection is already in the box.
- I can't use `onInputChange` because that is for typing rather than for menu selection. I need the post-menu-select, pre-box change.

If there are any workarounds please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you're after using `onChange`:

```jsx
const ref = useRef();
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

return (
  <Typeahead
    id="example"
    onChange={(selections) => {
      if (!selections.length || window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return setSelected(selections);
      }
      ref.current.clear();
    }}
    options={options}
    ref={ref}
    selected={selected}
  />
);
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-colden-w7ko9